# Why am am I still getting "E: Unable to locate package python-networkx" and "E: Unable to locate package python-pystache"?

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I am a beginner trying to learn Linux because my work requires me to do so. Currently I am tasked with setting up a Celadon compile machine. Following the steps given [here](https://01.org/projectceladon/documentation/getting-started/build-source), I am getting this two messages when following step 2.

```
 E: Unable to locate package python-networkx
 E: Unable to locate package python-pystache
```

Reading up more on it I tried doing `sudo apt-add-repository universe` and it shows:

> 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Can someone explain why it is unable to locate the package for me?

Answer (score 2):

Try using

`sudo apt install python3-networkx`

`sudo apt install python3-pystache`